# To be past participle

Tags: word-usage, grammar, sentence-construction, american-english, british-english

Please tell me, the below sentences are correct or not?

1. Work is to be done.
2. Work to be done.

As per my knowledge, there is nothing like ‘be+ to be+ past participle ‘
1st sentence can be written as, Work to be done is this or work to be done was this.

but i don’t know, please explain me .

Comment: There is work to be done.

Comment: The second one is not a complete sentence because it doesn't have a subject and a verb.  It could be correct as part of a larger sentence, though, like "*Work to be done* must be approved by a manager."

Answer (score 1):

> Work is to be done

a form of be + to be + past participle is prospective; it's not complete yet, but is intended to be so.

> Work to be done

This isn't a full sentence; it's a phrase. Again, this means something not complete yet but intended to be completed.